# Getting Source as Flatfile and to remove the Carriage returns and \n ...special charaters?

Tags: text-processing

I have an issue where I am getting a flatfile source with a huge number of records with PIPE delimiters and one of the fields is getting carriage returns (in multiple lines) and starts with a newline (`\n`). So how can I remove the `\n` character in the file?

Example:

```
-000123456|1654321|6/12/2002 8:49:20 AM|
tt Cynthia L Eggleston E456585 remove move the funds adv account in fcle flagged on 710091 pmt due 12-16- 15|
```

Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Comment: Is it suitable to remove all `\n` characters, or is there a special case when a `\n` is not desired?

Answer (score 2):

If you know, that this field begins with `\n` in all of the records, you can use `sed` as follows:

```
sed "N;s/|\n/|/"
```

to get rid of the new-line. Note, that since `sed` uses `\n` as line delimiters, you first have to join the next line to the one processed (the `N` command), during this process `sed` inserts the newline character between the joined lines.

If this problem arises randomly (not in every records), you'll have to resort to a stronger tool to parse the file content - basically you need to count the fields. Either `awk` or `perl` can do the trick elegantly (I think it could be accomplished in `sed` as well as the, but you probably don't want go [that direction](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/games/sokoban.sed.html)).

Comment: This only works for every other line - and `sed` is plenty strong enough to handle this - `sed` is only as strong as its script. Look into the `P;D;H;h;x;l` commands specifically. You can easily count fields in `sed` as well like : `s/field_delimiter/replace/3`

Comment: It *is supposed* to work like that - and it is exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score -2):

You can use many tools, but `sed` was built for exactly these kinds of situations:

```
 sed -i 's,\\n,,g' Flatfile
```

To show you how it works, here's the same expression with the input you provided just echoed:

```
$ echo '-000123456|1654321|6/12/2002 8:49:20 AM|\n tt Cynthia L Eggleston E456585 remove move the funds adv account in fcle flagged on 710091 pmt due 12-16- 15|' | sed 's,\\n,,g'
-000123456|1654321|6/12/2002 8:49:20 AM| tt Cynthia L Eggleston E456585 remove move the funds adv account in fcle flagged on 710091 pmt due 12-16- 15|
```

It just looks for the string `\n` and replaces it with an empty, zero-length string (effectively removing it). There are two `\`, so `\n` loses its special (newline character) meaning and can be matched as two characters.

Comment: This is not right. First of all `echo` doesnt recognize `\n` unless you use `echo -e`. Secondly `sed` doesnt recognize newlines either unless you append them to the pattern space as in the other answer.

Comment: The question was different when first asked, that's why the answer is now out of sync and appears wrong. I guess I should update it.